# mysql query issue for olympic medal tally

Tags: mysql

I have a table in mysql `olympic` and the field names are

```
country varchar, gold(int), silver(int), bronze(int)
```

please help me query with to arrange the data in ascending order just like olympic medal list.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT *
FROM `olympic`
ORDER BY `gold` DESC, `silver` DESC, `bronze` DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select 
country, 
Sum(gold) as gold, 
Sum(silver) as silver,
Sum(bronze) as bronze
from olympic 
group by country 
order by 
gold desc, silver desc, bronze desc
```

This will give you a list of countries with the medals they have achieved.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT country, gold, silver, bronze
FROM olympic
ORDER BY gold DESC, silver DESC, bronze DESC;
```